# How to use KaTeX auto-renderer in dynamically changing HTML?

Tags: katex

I have two beginner questions about using KaTeX auto-renderer. Both are related to the code below.

My first question: Do I need to use document.body in renderMathInElement? Can it be called only on the paragraph with id formula? If yes, how? I tried several ways, but nothing worked. Probably I just don't know the correct syntax.

My second question: After pressing the button, the changed text is not rendered. How and where shall I call renderMathInElement again to look for the new formulas in the page? Again, I tried several ways (including calling it right after changing the text), nothing worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- KaTeX requires the use of the HTML5 doctype. Without it, KaTeX may not render properly -->
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        renderMathInElement(document.body, {
            // ...options...
        });
    });
</script>
  </head>

    <body>
<p id="formula">Consider the circle with equation \(x^2+y^2=25\).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("formula");
  x.innerHTML = "Find the definite integral \(\int_0^1 xdx.\)";  
}
</script>

    </body>    

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, you can call `renderMathInElement` for any DOM element, e.g. the one you get for `document.getElementById("formula")`.
2. Calling `renderMathInElement(x)` essentially does what you want. Except that you also need to [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) the backslashes in your JavaScript string literal by doubling them.

Taken together you get something like this:

```js
let opts = {
  // ...options...
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  renderMathInElement(document.getElementById("formula"), opts);
});
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("formula");
  x.innerHTML = "Find the definite integral \\(\\int_0^1 xdx.\\)"; 
  renderMathInElement(x, opts);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p id="formula">Consider the circle with equation \(x^2+y^2=25\).</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change text</button>
```